# Simulate key press using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to simulate keyboard commands inside my application. Currently, I can press any arrow keys and I am able to capture the events fine. However, I am trying to simulate key events but I haven't had any luck.

Here is my code:

```js
  //Event
  this.remoteEvent = function(arg_event) {
    var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    var method = (typeof e.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined') ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";

    switch (arg_event) {
      case 'up':
        e[method]('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, 38);
        break;
      case 'right':
        e[method]('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, 39);
        break;
      case 'down':
        e[method]('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, 40);
        break;
      case 'left':
        e[method]('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, 37);
        break;
      case 'enter':
        e[method]('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, 13);
        break;
    }

    document.dispatchEvent(e);
  }
```

Am I approaching something wrong? I am aiming NOT to use jQuery and to be mostly cross-browser compatible.

Edit: Here is the the event that I am logging before dispatching:

```
KeyboardEvent {
  altGraphKey: false
  altKey: false
  bubbles: true
  cancelBubble: false
  cancelable: true
  charCode: 0
  clipboardData: undefined
  ctrlKey: false
  currentTarget: null
  defaultPrevented: false
  detail: 0
  eventPhase: 0
  keyCode: 0
  keyIdentifier: "false"
  keyLocation: 0
  layerX: 0
  layerY: 0
  location: 0
  metaKey: true
  pageX: 0
  pageY: 0
  path: NodeList[0]
  repeat: false
  returnValue: true
  shiftKey: false
  srcElement: document
  target: document
  timeStamp: 1410276114922
  type: "keydown"
  view: Window
  which: 0
}
```

Edit2: Here is my code to capture events:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', key_down_event, false);

//Key down event
function key_down_event(arg_event)
{
  //Ignore all key events if any modifier key is pressed
  if (arg_event.altKey || arg_event.ctrlKey || arg_event.metaKey || arg_event.shiftKey) return;

  //Get the source
  var source = arg_event.target;
  var destination = null;
  var direction = null;
  var escape = false;

  //Switch on key
  switch(arg_event.keyCode)
  {
    case VK_LEFT: direction = 'left'; break;
    case VK_RIGHT: direction = 'right'; break;
    case VK_DOWN: direction = 'down'; break;
    case VK_UP: direction = 'up'; break;
    case VK_ESC: escape = true; break;
  }
  if (!direction && !escape) return;

  arg_event.stopPropagation();
  arg_event.preventDefault();

  console.log(direction);
}
```

Comment: What exactly did not work? Why are you dispatching them on the `document`?

Comment: Nothing works. I am still able to capture events when I press keys on my physical keyboard but not keys I am trying to simulate. See my edit for the event thats being dispatched.

Comment: Can you show us the capturing code?

Comment: I added the capture code.

Comment: What is VK_LEFT, etc? Those values are not defined.

Comment: The char codes for each direction. Like var VK_LEFT = this.VK_LEFT = 37;

Comment: Digging further, it seems like metaKey is being set to true for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent, the `initKey*Event` method is completely broken. Compare the different APIs it offers:

- DOM2 old:

  ```
  void initKeyEvent(in DOMString typeArg, 
                    in boolean canBubbleArg, 
                    in boolean cancelableArg, 
                    in boolean ctrlKeyArg, 
                    in boolean altKeyArg, 
                    in boolean shiftKeyArg, 
                    in boolean metaKeyArg, 
                    in unsigned long keyCodeArg, 
                    in unsigned long charCodeArg, 
                    in views::AbstractView viewArg);
  ```
- DOM3 (no Gecko support):

  ```
  void initKeyboardEvent(in DOMString typeArg,
                         in boolean canBubbleArg,
                         in boolean cancelableArg,
                         in views::AbstractView viewArg,
                         in DOMString charArg,
                         in DOMString keyArg,
                         in unsigned long locationArg,
                         in DOMString modifiersListArg,
                         in boolean repeat);
  ```
- Webkit/Blink:

  ```
  void initKeyboardEvent(in DOMString typeArg,
                         in boolean canBubbleArg,
                         in boolean cancelableArg,
                         in views::AbstractView viewArg,
                         in DOMString keyIndentifierArg,
                         in unsigned long locationArg,
                         in boolean ctrlKeyArg,
                         in boolean altKeyArg,
                         in boolean shiftKeyArg,
                         in boolean metaKeyArg,
                         in boolean altGraphKeyArg)
  ```
- MSIE:

  ```
  void initKeyboardEvent(in DOMString typeArg,
                         in boolean canBubbleArg,
                         in boolean cancelableArg,
                         in views::AbstractView viewArg,
                         in DOMString keyArg,
                         in unsigned long locationArg,
                         in DOMString modifierListArg,
                         in boolean repeatArt,
                         in DOMString locationArg);
  ```

The spec notes:

> The initKeyboardEvent method is deprecated. Event constructor syntax […] is the expected future syntax for initializing a KeyboardEvent.

However, I couldn't find a spec that details the constructor initialisation. Until then, you may want to use [this polyfill](https://github.com/termi/DOM-Keyboard-Event-Level-3-polyfill).